# MySQL SELECT table.column AS table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I would like to know if it is safe to do something like this in MySQL queries:

I have a table  level (id,label,etc)

```
SELECT level.label AS level FROM level
```

I mean

```
SELECT table_name.column2_name AS table_name FROM table_name
```

Actually I'm calling "level" table from another table by a "JOIN", but I made it simpler to post it; and it works!

But I wanted to know if this will not cause some issues later.

Comment: use better naming. too many "level"s try to be more explicit.

Comment: There is "label" and "level" , maybe you didn't notice the difference, however I have edited the post like you want.

Comment: at any rate it's not a good idea. it can confuse the db in several joins or more complex queries. don't use the same name for table and column

Comment: Try SELECT table_name.column2_name AS col2 FROM table_name

Comment: Okay, but I don't think i will make queries that complex with this db. for an average db is it ok ? because i'm very stuck finding another name for this column wich will be appropriate. And also 
I am wondering why MySQL didn't refuse that, if it accepts it means that there is no problem doin this, otherwise it will throw some errors to me no?

Comment: Like I said it's not a good practice if you are happy with it ok. You may run to problems later. MySQL is not as strict but in some larger queries it gets confused and throws and error.

Comment: Ok, i got it i think i'll deal with it. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be perfectly fine doing this. I can make queries difficult to read - more complex ones than this, at any rate - so I wouldn't call it best practice, but if that's an appropriate name then use it. Another name might be LabelOfLevel which would get rid of the problem altogether....

Cheers -

Comment: So i think i'll use it because the software designed to use the db read tables in a certain way, and focus on table names, wouldn't be really  appropriate, but i can manage it if the query i wrote is very bad.